# Draw a 3D line with Irrlicht

Tags: 3d, line, irrlicht

I would like to draw a 3D segment from point (x1, y1, z1) to point (x2, y2, z2) in a Irrlicht 3D scene.

I am aware of the [line3d class](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1core_1_1line3d.html) and of this [addLine3d method](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1io_1_1_i_attributes.html#abbfb8cb612936e2f9c4b6728deb4b0c9) but I don't understand how to use them. What is this IAttributes class?

Can someone provide a minimal example of how to do draw a 3d line?
You can assume that I know how to add a Camera and draw the scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IAttributes is for serialization, you aren't trying to save a line, you want to draw one. Drawing something means setting the states in the driver (material and transforms), then telling the driver to draw it.

Your best option is to edit [example 3](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/example003.html) and replace `drawVertexPrimitiveList` with `draw3DLine`, then add your custom node to the scene manager like any other.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using `driver->draw3DLine(vector3df(x1, y1, z1), vector3df(x2, y2, z2));` which was exactly what I was looking for. I just called it between `driver->beginScene(...);` and `driver->endScene();` and it was enough.